# extract parent hierarchies from oracle

Tags: oracle

from an Oracle table with 2 columns (childName, parentName)

```
a, b
b, c
c, d
m, n
x, y
```

I want to get all parents hierarchies starting from child 'a' and return that as the table below

```
a, b
a, c
a, d
b, c
b, d
c, d
```

I've tried (updated)

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT childName AS childName, parentName
FROM table_parents
START WITH childName IN (
    SELECT 'a' as parentName FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT parentName FROM (
        SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT childName AS childName, parentName
        FROM table_parents
        START WITH childName = 'a'
        CONNECT BY PRIOR parentName = childName
    )
)
CONNECT BY PRIOR parentName = childName;
```

But I'm wondering if there is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
select     childname, connect_by_root parentname as parentname
from       table_parents
start with parentname in (
                           select     parentname
                           from       table_parents
                           start with childname = 'a'
                           connect by childname = prior parentname
                         )
connect by parentname = prior childname
;
```